# ASP.NET MVC5 project completely ignores SSL certificate from IIS for external requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have a Windows 2016 server running five ASP.NET MVC5 projects: Api (live), Api (dev), CMS (live), CMS (dev) and ASP.NET Identity. The SSL certificate of the Live CMS project has expired. When we update the SSL cert in IIS, it works as expected if you open the HTTPS page *locally* (on the VPS itself). But the problem is that no matter what we change or do, it still shows the old (expired) certificate when opening the HTTPS page from an external computer.

- After hours of digging and trying new things, we actually found out that deleting the old and expired certificates from the controlpanel of the hosting party (TransIP.nl) actually changed something. The certificate it was showing was no longer the expired certificate but now the certificate that is used for the other projects running in IIS (the live CMS has a different domain than the others do).
- Creating a new project in IIS with a copy of the sourcecode it does the exact same thing
- The certificate it now refers to is referenced in the code of the Identity project (not the CMS project code) in StartUp.cs (code below). This is the only place it's ever referenced. And of course IIS still binds the **correct** SSL certificate (checked multiple times).

  ```
      string certFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/x.pfx");

      var cert = new X509Certificate2(certFile, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["x"]);

      app.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
      {
          Factory = builder,
          RequireSsl = false,
          SigningCertificate = cert
      });
  ```

Do you guys have any idea where I could look next?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem was that the "Require Server Name Indication" option was untoggeled in a project that had the other SSL cert (the one that was incorrectly showing).